# Cell reference changes when looping over a table column in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm looping on a column called `ShopId` of the Table called `RegionSales` defined in `Sheet1` to insert lookup values in a column called `Total Sales`. One of the criteria for the lookup is the value in cell `B5` (sales region, ex: West). My code runs, but the problem is for the first four rows in `Total Sales` column, this criteria changes to `B1, B2, B3, B4`  rather than just staying at B5. After the fifth row to the last row, it stays `B5`. Why is the cell reference changing, and how can I solve it?

````
Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("RegionSales").DataBodyRange.Clear
Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("RegionSales").Resize Range("RegionSales[#All]").Resize(3,2)

'arrShops has all ShopId
n = Ubound(arrShops) - LBound(arrShops) + 1

For i = 10 to (n+9)
   Range("B" & i).Value = arrShops(i-10)
Next i

lastRow = Range("B10").End(xlDown).Row

For i = 10 to lastRow
    
    'Region Sales table content starts from 10 to lastRow
    'Column B is ShopId
    'Column C is Total Sales - pulls in value from a Table called ```Sales```
    'Problem with this criteria: B5 = Sales[Region]
    'One workaround is by using B" & 5 & "= Sales[Region]
    Range("C" & i).FormulaArray = "=IFERROR(INDEX(Sales[Net], Match(1, (B5 = Sales[Region])*(B" & i & " = Sales[ShopId]),0)),"""")"

Next i
````

Comment: `B5` should be `$B$5` if you want it to stay fixed.

Comment: It works. I didn't think about using ```$B$5```. Lol!